# setting image drawable from a class

Tags: android, image, drawable

I'm trying to set an image from a non Activity class, the drawable name is saved in a string and comes from another methor but the problem is that getPackageName() gives me this error: "cannot resolve method 'getPackageName()'" and I have no idea what to do, here is my code:

```
String[] string = printArray(false, context);

image1.getResources().getIdentifier(string[0] , "drawable", getPackageName());
image2.getResources().getIdentifier(string[1] , "drawable", getPackageName());
image3.getResources().getIdentifier(string[2] , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: where does the drawable located?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin at res/drawable-hdpi

Comment: can you post the whole class of the non activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `image1.getContext().getPackageName()`

Comment: That worked because it doesn't give an error but, it doesn't work when i try to do this:             
image1.setImageResource( image1.getResources().getIdentifier(string[0] , "drawable", image1.getContext().getPackageName()));

Comment: what is inside string[0] ?

Comment: The name of the image without the extension ofc

Comment: can you check that the result of 
image1.getResources().getIdentifier... returns something other than 0?

Comment: @user3272243 what fixed the issue?